# Не выполняет блок кода после цикла while в приложении для Виндоус "Python 3.9". Через коммандную строку все работает

Tags: python, while

Только начал учить Python. При запуске данного кода с файла в Python, цикл while выполняется и программа вылетает, не выводя последнюю часть "print" c "for". Пробовал делать цикл независимым от булевой переменной и прекращал его break, но эффект тот же... Пробовал добавлять к if фнкцию else, но не достиг успеха. Помогите пожалйста разобраться, в чем дело, чтобы после завершения цикла выполнялся следующий блок кода.
Обновлено:
Запустил с коммандной строки, все получилось.
Не правильно исполняется в приложении Python 3.9.
Буду рад помощи, если кто с таким сталкивался)

```
#Учусь заполнять словарь с помощью цикла while
responses = {}

# Создаю булевую переменную
polling_active = True

#сам цыкл
while polling_active:
    #задаю вопросы для создания ключа и значения для словаря
    name = input("\nWhat your name? ")
    response = input("Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ")

    #сохраняю результат в словарь
    responses[name] = response

    #спрашиваю про продолжение
    repeat = input("\nWould you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")

    #условие прекращения работы цикла
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False

# Вивод конечного результата после завершения цикла
# Который и не работает, программа завершается после смены переменной polling_active = False
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(f"{name.title()} would like to climb {response.title()}.")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй просто поставить в условие цикла true, а в условии отмены просто break

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.

Comment: Попробовал, тот же результат. Программа вылетает сразу после введения "no"

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код рабочий, но я бы дал вам совет:

Здесь `if repeat == 'no':` вы проверяете равен ли ввод `no`, но а что если пользователь введёт `No` или `NO`? Лучше приводить к нижнему регистру с помощью `lower()` - > `if repeat.lower() == 'no':`

Также подробнее о методах строк вы можете посмотреть [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду учитывать при дальнейшем обучении!